# virtual directory on iis-express looking for assemblies in non-existing bin directory

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I have a site that uses an external virtual directory (being shared with other websites)

When I load the project with iis-express (visual studio 2017 debug) in order to see these files I've configured them according to this article: 
[How to create a virtual directory in iis-express](https://josephwoodward.co.uk/2014/01/how-to-create-a-virtual-directory-in-iis-express)

My problem is a 500 error when trying to access anything in those directory (static content) due to missing assembly in non-existing bin directory (which is actually sitting on my main website.

How can I prevent the virtual directory from trying to load any assembly when serving this static content ? 
The virtual directory web.config doesn't hold any reference to those assemblies.

Comment: "My problem is a 500 error when trying to access anything in those directory (static content) due to missing assembly in non-existing bin directory (which is actually sitting on my main website." Show the entire error page, as well as the directory structure.

Comment: the main site is in one dir c:\inetpub\website\main and the other direcotries are c:\inetpub\websites\pictures  for example. the main dir has all the subfolders (bin, app_code ect) the pictures has only pictures. the error is missing assembly in \pictures\bin (which is actually in main\bin)